# How can I wrap the last character in an element if it's a certain character?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am back and forth with this but I think I am so close. I want to wrap the last character of all H1 tags in a div with class .content if it is a full stop or question mark (to apply color). Here is what I have:

```
$(function() {
    $('.content h1').each(function() {
        last = $(this).text().trim().slice(-1);
        if(last === '.' || last === '?') {
            alert(last);
            //last.wrap('<span class="orange-end"></span>');
        }
    });
});
```

This will alert the last character correctly, I am just struggling to wrap and return.

Cheers all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
    $('.content h1').each(function() {
      // get the text
      var text = this.innerHTML.trim();
      
      //do logic if the last character is a period or question mark
      if (['.', '?'].indexOf(text.slice(-1)) > -1) {
        // set the html back to what it was, replacing the last 
        // character with the wrapped html
        this.innerHTML = text.slice(0, -1) 
                       + '<span class="orange-end">'
                       + text.slice(-1)
                       + '</span>'; 
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.orange-end { color: orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <h1>What is the meaning of this?</h1>
  <h1>No way!</h1>
  <h1>I know.</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome cheers. Nothing like realizing you have a lot to learn after posting a question, ha ha.

Comment: @generalcb the important point here is that you can't really use jQuery wrap with a string.  It's meant to be used with dom nodes.  So if you are trying to change part of text node, imho, it's easier to just replace the value with what you want.